# Objective-C method signatures: Parameter types can differ between declaration and implementation?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can declare a method in the `@interface` having parameter type `NSString*`:

```
- (id) initWithString:(NSString*)str;
```

while in the implementation it is `NSNumber*`:

```
- (id) initWithString:(NSNumber*)str
```

For a full example, see the code below. When calling `[Work test]` the output is `a.x = Hi`, so the passed-in `NSString*` went through and one can see that the "correct" `initWithString` method was called.

**Why is this code accepted by the compiler?**

**Can I make the compiler complain when parameter types differ?**

Citing from Apple's documentation [Defining Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html) :

> The only requirement is that the signature matches, which means you must keep the name of the method as well as the parameter and return types exactly the same.

My test code:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *x;

- (id) initWithString:(NSString*)str;
- (void) feed:(NSString*)str;

@end

@implementation ClassA

- (id) initWithString:(NSNumber*)str
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.x = str;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) feed:(NSNumber*)str
{
    self.x = str;
}

@end


@implementation Work

+ (void) test
{
    ClassA *a = [[ClassA alloc] initWithString:@"Hi"];
    NSLog(@"a.x = %@", a.x);
}

@end
```

I added the `feed` method to see, whether it is "special" to `init`-like methods, but the compiler doesn't complain either.
(Ran this on Yosemite / Xcode 6.4 / iOS8.4 Simulator.)

PS: If I didn't use the right terms, please correct me :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I make the compiler complain when parameter types differ?

There's a warning for this which you can activate by including the following line in the header:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wmethod-signatures"
```

You can also put `-Wmethod-signatures` into the project's "Other Warning Flags" Xcode build setting to activate this for the whole project.

I don't really understand why Apple is so hesitant to activate helpful warnings like this by default.

My standard pattern on virtually every project is to put `-Weverything` in "Other Warning Flags". This activates all warnings clang has to offer.

Since there are some warnings that are a little too pedantic or don't serve my coding style, I individually deactivate unwanted warning types as they pop up.

Comment: Thanks - the warning is helping me the most. I'll accept your answer. The `-Weverything` will be my friend in the future. Unfortunately for my current project it would most certainly blow all schedules and deadlines to pieces :-) - And I totally agree with the missing default warnings. Especially for a project with a long line of "developer heritage" more warnings would have been nice.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C a method is defined as a string (known as a selector) in the form of `doSomethingWithParam:anotherParam:`. Or in your case it will be `initWithString:`. Note there's no parameter types in these strings. One side-effect of defining methods like this is that Objective-C, unlike Java or C++ doesn't allow overloading operators by just changing the parameter type. Another side-effect is the behavior you observed.

EDIT: Additionally, it appears that the compiler does **not** look at the implementation at all when checking method calls, just the interface. Proof: declare a method in a header, don't specify any implementation for that method, and call this method from your code. This will compile just fine, but of course you'll get an "unrecognized selector" exception when you run this code.

It'd be great if someone could provide a nice explanation of the default compiler behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - however, I set it to YES, but my test project does not complain with any warnings or errors. Do I have to change more / other settings?

Comment: @RainerSchwarze it won't give you error for implementing the method with the different type. But it will give you a compile-time warning if you pass a parameter of a different type (like a `NSNumber` instead of a `NSString`).

Comment: Upon a closer look, this compiler flag doesn't make a difference here. I'll edit my answer. The rest of my explanation still stands.

Comment: When you search for "YetAnotherType" in the "Defining Classes" documentation from Apple there is a little box with examples, which methods will be different - shouldn't then the 1st and the 3rd example be the same instead of different? ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html )

Comment: @RainerSchwarze I'm afraid I don't understand your last comment. I just added an edit to my question, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised by the quote you found stating that param and return types matter to the uniqueness of the method signature. Re-reading, *I think you found a bug [in the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html)*.

Defining a parameter type in the interface will generate a warning for callers that do not pass that type (or cast the parameter to that type), no matter the implementation.  Changing the parameter type in the implementation is exactly like casting the parameter within the method.  Nothing wrong with that, not even a cause for warning. So long as the different type shares methods (polymorphic or inherited) with the declared type.

In other words, restating by example...

The following will cause a compiler error, proving that distinct param types offers no distinction to the compiler (same is true for return type)...

```
// .h
- (void)foo:(NSString *)str;

// .m
- (void)foo:(NSString *)str {    
    NSLog(@"called foo %@", [str class]);
}

- (void)foo:(NSNumber *)str {    <----- duplicate declaration error
}
```

The following will cause no compiler warnings, errors or runtime errors...

```
// .h
- (void)foo:(NSString *)str;

// .m
- (void)foo:(NSNumber *)str {
    // everything implements 'class', so no problem here
    NSLog(@"called foo %@", [str class]);
}
```

The following is exactly like the previous example in every respect...

```
// .h
- (void)foo:(NSString *)str;

// .m
- (void)foo:(NSString *)str {
    NSNumber *number = (NSNumber *)str;
    NSLog(@"called foo %@", [number class]);
}
```

The following will cause no warnings, but will generate a runtime error because we are abusing the cast by invoking a method that the passed type doesn't implement (presuming the caller calls with a string as the interface indicates)...

```
// .h
- (void)foo:(NSString *)str;

// .m
- (void)foo:(NSNumber *)str {
    NSLog(@"does str equal 2? %d", [str isEqualToNumber:@2]); <--- crash!
}
```

All of the foregoing matches intuition and behavior in practice, just not that passage in the doc.  Interesting find!

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you know, if I could somehow get a warning when the parameter type changes in the implementation? (maybe with an analyzer?) I'm working on a project with about 200 .m files (without pods) and now I am quite interested in checking for this kind of issue :-)

Comment: I don't think the clang analysis will catch this.  Retyping parameters is equivalent to casting.  The errors - if there are any - cannot be found statically.  It doesn't seem like it would be too hard to roll your own static check for just this one practice we're discussing.  p.s. I've reported doc bugs before to apple (with slow but eventual success).

Comment: @danh Regarding your first sentence: Why do you think parameter and return types are not part of the signature in objc? There's a whole class named `NSMethodSignature` whose single purpose is to manage the types of parameters and return value. To me an Objective-C method signature is in concept quite similar to what it is in C and serves the same purpose.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, I think we must distinguish NSMethodSignature runtime behavior from clang.  The latter demonstrably conflates methods with the same name but different param or return types.